# Vsto multiple range

Tags: c#, excel, range, vsto

Maybe somebody can help me. I try to write multiple range to Excel sheet, but that didn't work.

First, I can write one range to Excel with a following code:

```
rangeO = ws.get_Range("A1","K7500");
rangeO.Value = RegiObj;
```

Possible to write one more range to excel sheet? The "RegiObj" is a 2 dimension object array, "ws" is the current worksheet.

I tried the following code (and more), but nothing works:

```
   object Obj1 = regie;// tried with string[], int array
   Range elRange = ws.get_Range("N2", "N7500");
   elRange.Value2 = Obj1;

   elRange = ws.get_Range("O2", "O7500");
   elRange.Value = elozoleg;// elozoleg is string[] array
```

What did I  miss?

Sorry for bad language

Screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjxYf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write data into a two-dimensional array of cells, your source array must also be two-dimensional.  The number of rows and columns must match.  The 0th dimension corresponds to rows.

```
var range = worksheet.Range["A1", "C10"];
var array = new object[10, 3];
for (int row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < array.GetLength(1); col++)
        array[row, col] = string.Format("{0}{1}", (char)('A' + col), row + 1);
range.Value = array;
```

Comment: If i would like to write any range(if a range has 1 column?), i need 2-dimensional array? I may have been wrong. I would like to write another ranges ( 3 piece 1 column). After i wrote one range, i can not write anymore more range. I uploaded a picture.

Comment: Sorry for, the late answer! Thank you for the answer! In the my code the problem was the next: i missed the for loops to upload my (int,string)array. But if you use object[] array, no need loops, just this: 
rangeO.Value = RegiObj;
RegiObj is object[] array.